# Cannot call assembly function from C kernel

Tags: c, assembly, x86, kernel, inline-assembly

I am writing a 32-bit C kernel and I tried to call a function that I wrote in assembly.
So I wrote an assembly file containing the function `myfunc` and then I wrote the kernel which defined `myfunc` as a global variable and I linked them together so I can use it in my C code.
It worked fine, but when I tried to call it, it caused a triple fault.
However, if I use inline assembly instead,

```
asm("call myfunc");
```

It does the job.
Also notice that the disassembly for `asm("call myfunc");` and for `myfunc();` aren't similar:

The disassembly when using `myfunc()`:

```
00000000 <kmain>:
   0:   f3 0f 1e fb             endbr32 
   4:   53                      push   ebx
   5:   83 ec 08                sub    esp,0x8
   8:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   9 <kmain+0x9>
   d:   81 c3 02 00 00 00       add    ebx,0x2
  13:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   14 <kmain+0x14>
  18:   f4                      hlt    
  19:   83 c4 08                add    esp,0x8
  1c:   5b                      pop    ebx
  1d:   c3                      ret
```

The disassembly when using `asm("call myfunc");`:

```
00000000 <kmain>:
   0:   f3 0f 1e fb             endbr32 
   4:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   5 <kmain+0x5>
   9:   f4                      hlt    
   a:   c3                      ret
```

Here's how I build it:

```
nasm -f elf32 kernel/klink.asm -o klink.o
gcc -c kernel/main.c -m32 -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -O1 -fno-builtin
ld -m elf_i386 -T link.ld -o KERNEL klink.o main.o
objcopy --dump-section .text=KERNEL.SYS KERNEL
```

`link.ld`:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)
ENTRY(kmain)
SECTIONS
{
   . = 0x100000;
   .text : { *(.text) }
}
```

The kernel (`main.c`):

```
void kmain() {
   extern void myfunc();
   myfunc();                 //Here it causes a triple fault.
   //asm("call myfunc");     //But this works fine.
   asm("hlt");
}
```

And this is the assembly file that contains the function (`klink.asm`):

```
[BITS 32]

SECTION .text
    GLOBAL start                 ;define start as a global variable
    GLOBAL myfunc                ;also myfunc
    jmp start                    ;jump straight into start
    myfunc:
        ;idk what to write here... just some code :)
    
    EXTERN kmain                 ;define kmain as an external variable
    
    start:
        jmp kmain                ;jump into kmain
```

Comment: What [x86, I assume] processor mode is `kmain` started with? Is it 16 bit real mode, 32 bit protected mode, etc.? Are the page tables set up [and who does this]? Has the stack pointer been set up and what address? What mode is `kmain` compiled for? What mode is `myfunc` assembled for? What are the addresses that `kmain` and `myfunc` assigned. What is the disassembly for `kmain` for _both_ cases (e.g. `myfunc();` and `asm("call myfunc");`? They should be similar.

Comment: @CraigEstey The disassembly for `myfunc()` and `asm("call myfunc")` aren't similar.

Comment: They _should_ be. `myfunc` takes _no_ arguments and returns `void`, so the code for `myfunc();` should just be `call myfunc`. If not, _that_ is a clue. Perhaps you should _edit_ your question and post the disassembly of _both_ cases in separate code blocks here. Again, what about the asm based setup code that is invoked before `kmain` is called to initialize the CPU enough so that a C program can run? That code is normally what `start` does. If the `jmp start` in `klink.asm` is _literally_ the first inst executed, again, who sets up segment registers, stack pointer, etc?

Comment: Try using `-fno-pic` compiler option.

Comment: @Jester What does it mean?

Comment: `-fno-pic` or `-fno-pie` will tell GCC not to look for a GOT, and not to try to call through a PLT.  `-fPIE` is the default on modern distros, and makes really clunky inefficient 32-bit code because it doesn't support RIP-relative addressing.  Your disassembly omitted `-r` so you're not actually seeing the right call-target; it's probably `call __x86.get_pc_thunk.bx`.  Look at `gcc -S` output, or `objdump -drwC -Mintel` if you want to disassemble your `.o` instead of linked `ld` output.